# Xdebug in Visual Studio Code not allowing breakpoints in non-php files

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, breakpoints

Visual Studio Code is only allowing me to place Xdebug breakpoints on `.php` files but not on `.module` files.

Is there some configuration that I need to change? Thank you.

Comment: as a workaround im using  xdebug_break(); which works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VSCODE PHP DEBUG extension defines that it [contributes](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/blob/b07f71baca9e49a210834927c641cb584ea6d285/package.json#L172) breakpoints to the PHP language. Thus, vscode will allow setting breakpoints on files that are associated to the language.

If you use a non standard file extension, you can do one of the following:

1. When the file is open, select the language on the bottom right side of the IDE.
   [image]

You will need to do this every time you open the file.

You can also press CTRL/CMD + P, then type `>Change Language Mode` and a menu will pop up and you can select the PHP language. There are also options presented to set up file associations.

2. Create a local or global `settings.json` with

```json
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.module": "php"
  }
}
```

3. Another - not so nice - option is to allow breakpoints regardless of file language mode.

Add this to your `settings.json`

```json
{
  "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true
}
```