# Xdebug Visual Studio code for different extensions PHP

Tags: visual-studio-code, drupal, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug extension for Visual Studio Code and it works perfectly for `.php` file. But I am developing a Drupal website and, placing debugger on `.theme` or `.module` file, Xdebug doesn't work, probably because file's extension isn't php.

Can I add other extensions like `.theme` or `.module` for Xdebug?

Answer (score 2):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77047960) but to repeat. You need to tell VS Code that these other extensions should also be considered PHP files.

In your settings.json (either workspace or user) add

```json
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.module": "php",
    "*.theme": "php"
  }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!